# x editable and codeigniter: display error message if data not updated into db

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling, datatable, x-editable

In my application I have a dataTable to display record from db, I am trying to edit record using x-editable and its working fine. But the problem is I want to display an error message if submitted data not updated successfully into the db.

I tried 'success:' but it triggered after submit the form whatever the data reach the db or not, but i want to trigger the success if controller return true.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are processing the editable submission using ajax you need to set:

```
echo 1; //if model returns true
```

and

```
echo 0; //if model returns false
```

in the controller.

Then in the ajax reponse you need to check in the script:

(Consider the response variable is **response**)

```
if(response==1)
{
  alert('Update Success.');
}
else
{
  alert('Update Failure !')
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It works. Do me another favor, How can i reset the old value if unsuccessful? by default it shows new value.

Comment: if ajax returns false, there is no change occured in db,,,, so u can simply refreshes the page, it will displays the previous value..... if the editable items are displayed using ajax, u can simply recall that ajax..

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier if you provided us with a code sample.

If you're working with ActiveRecord, you can always use:

```
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```